# IMPLEMENTING SCROLLING CAMERA

Tags: python

I want to add a camera that follows my player I do not want everything to move I just want the player to move and the window follows  that way I can add multiplayer to it please help me fix this problem for I have looked everywhere but it helps very little it here is my code I added a player class and I tried doing win.scroll(x, y) but it does not work please help me

```
import pygame
import os

##===========================================WINDOW AND INIT==============================================##
pygame.init()
win_height = 400
win_width = 800
win = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width, win_height))
pygame.display.set_caption(('OTHER WORLD'))

##=========================================IMAGES AND COLORS==============================================##
stationary = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'standing.png'))
left = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'L1.png')),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'L2.png')),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'L3.png')),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'L4.png')),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'L5.png')),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'L6.png')),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'L7.png')),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'L8.png')),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'L9.png'))
        ]
right = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'R1.png')),
         pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'R2.png')),
         pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'R3.png')),
         pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'R4.png')),
         pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'R5.png')),
         pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'R6.png')),
         pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'R7.png')),
         pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'R8.png')),
         pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'R9.png'))
         ]
up = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'U1.png')),
      pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'U2.png')),
      pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'U3.png')),
      pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'U4.png')),
      pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'U5.png')),
      pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'U6.png')),
      pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'U7.png')),
      pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'U8.png')),
      pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'U9.png'))
      ]
down = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'D1.png')),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'D2.png')),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'D3.png')),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'D4.png')),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'D5.png')),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'D6.png')),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'D7.png')),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'D8.png')),
        pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Hero', 'D9.png'))
        ]
background = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('water.png'), (win_width, win_height))
grass = pygame.mixer.Sound(('stepsongrass.wav'))


##================================================PLAYER==================================================##
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
##================================================WALK====================================================##
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.velx = 10
        self.face_right = True
        self.face_left = False
        self.face_up = False
        self.face_down = False
        self.stepIndex = 0
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, 64, 64)

    def move_player(self, userInput):
        if userInput[pygame.K_d] and self.x < win_width - 30:
            grass.play()
            self.x += self.velx
            self.face_right = True
            self.face_left = False
            self.face_up = False
            self.face_down = False
        elif userInput[pygame.K_a] and self.x > 0:
            grass.play()
            self.x -= self.velx
            self.face_right = False
            self.face_left = True
            self.face_up = False
            self.face_down = False
        elif userInput[pygame.K_w] and self.y > 0:
            grass.play()
            self.y -= self.velx
            self.face_right = False
            self.face_left = False
            self.face_up = True
            self.face_down = False
        elif userInput[pygame.K_s] and self.y < win_height - 50:
            grass.play()
            self.y += self.velx
            self.face_right = False
            self.face_left = False
            self.face_up = False
            self.face_down = True
        else:
            self.stepIndex = 0
            grass.stop()

    def draw(self, win):
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, 32 , 47)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), self.hitbox, 1)
        if self.stepIndex >= 33:
            self.stepIndex = 0
        if self.face_left:
            win.blit(left[self.stepIndex // 4], (self.x, self.y))
            self.stepIndex += 1
        if self.face_right:
            win.blit(right[self.stepIndex // 4], (self.x, self.y))
            self.stepIndex += 1
        if self.face_up:
            win.blit(up[self.stepIndex // 4], (self.x, self.y))
            self.stepIndex += 1
        if self.face_down:
            win.blit(down[self.stepIndex // 4], (self.x, self.y))
            self.stepIndex += 1

##==============================================DRAW GAME=================================================##
def draw_game():
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    win.blit(background, (0, 0))
    player.draw(win)
    if userInput[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        pygame.time.delay(10)
    else:
        pygame.time.delay(30)
    pygame.display.update()

player = Player(250, 290)

##==============================================MAIN LOOP=================================================##
run = True
while run:

##==============================================QUIT GAME=================================================##
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

##================================================INPUT===================================================##
    userInput = pygame.key.get_pressed()

##==============================================MOVEMENT==================================================##
    player.move_player(userInput)

##=========================================DRAW GAME IN WINDOW============================================##
    draw_game()
```

Comment: This is a lot of code, can you extract a smaller [example]. Maybe you could split your large code into separate blocks. Important: What did you try to __debug and locate the error__ ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't SHOUT.